# Use of dp and dpi instead of percentages in android?

Tags: android, dpi

I have understood the concept of dp and dpi for different layouts and images being used in android. But my doubt (sorry if dumb) is why did android come up with a concept of density pixel, density independent pixel instead of percentages just like in html. It is getting difficult for the developer..

Comment: Read this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Answer (score 3):

Because of to support multiple screens android introduced this dp and dip concepts

**dp or dip**

From the [Android Documentation for Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

> **Density-independent Pixels** - an abstract unit that is based on the physical density of the screen. These units are relative to a **160
>   dpi** screen, so one dp is one pixel on a **160 dpi** screen.
>
> **Use of dp:**
>
> **Density independence** - Your application achieves *“density independence”* when it preserves the physical size (from the user’s
>   point of view) of user interface elements when displayed on screens
>   with different densities. (ie) The image should look the same size
>   (not enlarged or shrinked) in different types of screens.
>
> **Density-independent** pixel is a virtual pixel unit that you should use when defining UI layout, to express layout dimensions or position
>   in a density-independent way.
>
> **The density-independent pixel** is equivalent to one physical pixel
>   on a **160 dpi** screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the
>   system for a "medium" density screen.  At runtime, the system
>   transparently handles any scaling of the dp units, as necessary, based
>   on the actual density of the screen in use. The conversion of `dp`
>   units to screen `pixels` is simple: **px = dp * (dpi / 160)**.
>
> For example, on a `240 dpi` screen, `1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels`.
>   You should always use `dp` units when defining your application's UI,
>   to ensure proper display of your UI on screens with different
>   densities.

Comment: Thanks Shylendra. What should i do to position the widgets in a particular positions. Right now I am working for S3 but later I have to deploy the same application in different mobiles of different resolutions. What should I do to make the UI look alike in all of them.

Comment: you need to maintain those widgets in different folders like 
res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density

Comment: yeah I was working on that and I have divided my layout folder into 4 catogories... Is there any info like for what range of resolutions the  low, medium high and xhigh layouts must be called.

Comment: refer this for more info http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html